# Cannot install djangorestframework on ec2 instance with pip

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, django-rest-framework

I use a micro ec2 instance with python 2.7.10 installed.
When i try to install djangorestframework with "pip install djangorestframework", it failed and here is the log:

Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(, 'Connection to pypi.python.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')'

Comment: It's up for me. Do you have a proxy, firewall or anything else that could be preventing your connection?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is pip will open a https connection to pyip. Re-check outbound security rule of the instance and add https rule